# Showing that the map $t\mapsto(t,t^2,t^3)$ is continuous in Zariski Topology. Twisted Cubic.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, zariski-topology

Consider the affine space $\mathbb{A}^n$ where $\mathbb{A}^n$ is the set of $n$-tuples $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ with $a_i\in k$, and $k$ is an algebraically closed field.

Next, consider the map $f:\mathbb{A}^1\to \mathbb{A}^3$ given by
$$t\mapsto(t,t^2,t^3).$$
I want to show that this map is continuous with respect to Zarisky topology (closed sets are given as a vanishing set of some polynomials).

In other words, I want to show that the preimage of every closed set is closed.

1. We can show that the image of $f$ is a closed set i.e. $f(\mathbb{A})=Z(I)$ for some $I\in k[x,y,z]$.
2. Next, if $X$ is any closed set of $\mathbb{A}^3$ with $X\cap Z(I)=\emptyset$, then $f^{-1}(X\cap Z(I))=\emptyset$ is closed. So, I am only interested in closed sets that intersect $f(\mathbb{A})$ nontrivially.
3. Consider a closed set $X$ of $\mathbb{A}^3$ with $X\cap f(A)\neq\emptyset$. Since $f(\mathbb{A})=Z(I)$, then $X\cap f(\mathbb{A})$ is closed. So,
   $$f^{-1}(X\cap f(\mathbb{A}))=f^{-1}(X)\cap \mathbb{A}$$
   as $f$ is a bijection with it's image $f(\mathbb{A})$.
   Now, we want to show that $f^{-1}(X)$ is closed.

Can I think about $f^{-1}(X)$ as $Z(f^*(J))$ where $X=Z(J)$ as $X$ is closed subset and $f^*$ is the dual map to $f:\mathbb{A}^1\to \mathbb{A}^3$ on the level on rings i.e.
$$f^*:k[x,y,z]\to k[t]$$
where $x=t$, $y=t^2$, and $z=t^3$? In that case, I can see that $f^{-1}(X)=Z(f^*(J))$ is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the identity $f^{-1}(X) = Z(f^*(J))$,
Observe that both  $p \in f^{-1}(X)$ and $p \in Z(f^{*}(J))$ are equivalent to $f(p) \supset J$.

More concretely, let $p=(t-a)$ and $J = (g_1(x,y,z),g_2(x,y,z)..,g_n(x,y,z))$.
$p \in f^{-1}(X)$
⇔ $f((t-a)) \in X$
⇔ $(x-a,y-a^2,z-a^3) \supset (g_k(x,y,z))$ for every $k$.
⇔ $g_k(a,a^2,a^3) = 0$ for every $k$.

$p \in Z(f^{*}(J))$
⇔ $(t-a) \supset (f^{*}(g_k(x,y,z)))$ for every $k$.
⇔ $(t-a) \supset (g_k(t,t^2,t^3))$ for every $k$.
⇔ $g_k(a,a^2,a^3) = 0$ for every $k$.

Comment: Does it work in general that if $P\in Z(f^*J)$ then $f^*h(P)=0$ i.e. $h(f(P))=0$. So, $f(P)\in Z(J)$ i.e. $P\in f^{-1}(X)$? To show the opposite inclusion, just reverse the order of the previous derivation.

Answer (score 1):

$f(t)=(t,t^2,t^3)$, $W=(x,y,z)$, if $X=Z(g_1(W),\ldots,g_n(W))$ is a closed set of $\Bbb{A}^3$ then $f^{-1}(X)=Z(g_1(f(t)),\ldots,g_n(f(t)))$ is closed in $\Bbb{A}^1$

Thus $f^{-1}(\Bbb{A}^3-X)=\Bbb{A}^1 - f^{-1}(X)$ is open and $f$ is continuous.